# Symfony assets generation css link and script src include more spaces

Tags: symfony, assetic

Hi guys when i use assets in symfony 2.7 for some reason it includes more space character before the links and script tags.

**Code**:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
{% block title -%}<title>Title</title>{% endblock %}

{% block metadesc -%}<meta name="description" content="">{% endblock %}

{% block metakey -%}<meta name="keywords" content="">{% endblock %}

<meta name="author" content="Publicis Modem Cybermark">
{% block stylesheets -%}
    {% stylesheets
    '@PagesBundle/Resources/public/css/normalize.css'
    '@PagesBundle/Resources/public/css/main.css' %}
    <link href="{{ asset(asset_url) }}" rel="stylesheet">
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascriptshd -%}
    {% javascripts
    '@PagesBundle/Resources/public/js/htmlshiv3.7.2.js'
    '@PagesBundle/Resources/public/js/respond.min.js' %}
    <script src="{{ asset(asset_url) }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Result of code**

[image]

So the blocks are properly formatted why is including this indentation to the script and the link.

Comment: What is you indentation style, space or tab, have you tried to remove line break when you declare you block ? Consider you can use `<spaceless>` function : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/spaceless.html

Comment: I think they are two tabs. See the image. And yes i have try to remove all but the style of the code need to be completely removed....

Answer (score 0):

You should use `{% spaceless %}{% endspaceless %}` tag to remove all the space inside a block or use `{%- -%}`  instead of `{% %}`.

Here you only remove the space from the opening block, you should do the same for all the `{%` of use the spaceless tag

Comment: It removes all the spaces also the new line and they are on the same line... I want every link and script to be on its own line.

Comment: why do you want that ? browser doesn't care about space between html tags

Comment: Because i want the code to be beautifully aligned when i open it and quickly investigate if problem exists.